# Stiffness problem in an NDSolve system. StiffnessSwitching does not help?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve an ODE system with the NDSolve method. This my ODE system, with the BC and the functions V and dV defined:

[image: ODE system, with BC in (4) and the function V(B) and dV(B) defined in (5)]

```
    s = NDSolve[{F'[
  t] == -(2 /Sqrt[3]) (F[t]^2/2 + a[t]^2*  V[B[ t]])^(1/2)*F[t] - 
  a[t]^2*dV[B[t]], 
a'[t] == a[t]/Sqrt[3] (F[t]^2/2 + a[t]^2*  V[B[ t]])^(1/2), 
B'[t] == F[t], F[tmin] == Subscript[v, 0], a[tmin] == a0 , 
B[tmin] == Subscript[B, 0] }, {F, a, B}, {t, tmin, tmax}, Method->"ExplicitRungeKutta"]
```

Where the solution functions are:

```
F(t), a(t), B(t)
```

I need the solutions for a big interval, like:

```
t = [-10^(10), -10^(-10)]
```

So:

```
tmin = -10^(10)
tmax = -10^(-10)
```

But the system seems to be stiff. I'm trying to replace the "ExplicitRungeKutta" method for "StiffnessSwitching method", replacing the method with:

```
Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}
```

But the system seems to remain stiff.

The complete code is:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];

V[B_] := 3;
dV[B_] :=  V'[B];

B0 = 1;
F0 = 0;
a0 = 10^(-10);

tmin = -10^(10);
tmax = -10^(-10);

  s = NDSolve[{F'[
  t] == -(2 /Sqrt[3]) (F[t]^2/2 + a[t]^2*  V[B[ t]])^(1/2)*F[t] - 
  a[t]^2*dV[B[t]], 
a'[t] == a[t]/Sqrt[3] (F[t]^2/2 + a[t]^2*  V[B[ t]])^(1/2), 
B'[t] == F[t], F[tmin] == F0, a[tmin] == a0 , B[tmin] == B0 }, {F,
 a, B}, {t, tmin, tmax},  Method->"ExplicitRungeKutta"]
```

**Question: Is there any way to obtain the solutions of these equations without stiffness? What method should I use?**

I'd appreciate much all the answers.

Comment: What if you just use `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` without invoking RK at all?

Comment: (1) What's `v0`? (2) What if it's a singularity and not stiffness?

Comment: Are `tmin` & `tmax` switched, or is `tmin` supposed to be greater than `tmax`?

Comment: V0 was F0, sorry for the mistake. And both variables tmin and tmax were negative (another mistake writting the code here).

Comment: And the stiffnessSwitching method alone does not solve the (aparent) stiffness problem.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?  Or do you need some more help?

Answer (score 3):

Let's read the error message:

> NDSolve`Iterate::ndsz: At t == -1.*10^10, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

The "step size is **effectively** zero" means that in floating-point arithmetic `t + dt` is equal to `t` for the computed time step `dt`.  If this is the problem, increasing working precision might help.

```
de = {F'[t] == -(2/Sqrt[3]) (F[t]^2/2 + a[t]^2*V[B[t]])^(1/2)*F[t] - 
     a[t]^2*dV[B[t]], 
   a'[t] == a[t]/Sqrt[3] (F[t]^2/2 + a[t]^2*V[B[t]])^(1/2), 
   B'[t] == F[t]};
ics = {F[tmin] == F0, a[tmin] == a0, B[tmin] == B0};
s = 
 NDSolve[{de, ics}, {F, a, B}, {t, tmin, tmax},
  PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Note:*
The first of the OP's differential equations has

```
F'[t] == <..stuff..> * F[t]
```

because `dV[B]` is zero and the second terms goes away.
Since `F[t]` starts out at `F[tmin] == 0`, that means `F[t]` is a constant `0` (zero).  Thus the third differential equation `B'[t] == F[t]` and its initial condition imply `B[t]` is a constant `1` (one).